# how to use javascript to extract and show a random text from a datalist when using onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, datalist

I would like that a JavaScript function could take a random sentence from a datalist in the same file, and then show it when I click on a button with an "onclick" event. I am looking for the easiest way to do that. Does anyone have an example?

(Just looking around, trying JavaScript for the first time)

Comment: You need to provide more information if you'd like someone to answer. What is the "data list"? Is it an array of strings? An array of objects? An object?
You say "the same file"... you're going to have the javascript in the same file as the data? (It would make more sense to pull it from an external source).

What are you looking for? It makes a big difference. We need more information about the data (the haystack) and the search parameters (the needle).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did a datalist tag in html with some options tag on it (maybe that is not the good way to do it), and I just want to get sentences from there to show up when i click a button. I did a little script at the end of the page in javascript to try to make it but that doesnt work. I already tried the javascript method with the parenthesis, and trying to uses sentences from there, it worked, but i need something a bit easier to manage

Answer (score 1):

```js
let dataList =["sentence 1","sentence 2","sentence 3","sentence 4"]
let div = document.getElementById('asd')
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click",myFunc)

function myFunc(){
   let x = parseInt(Math.random()* dataList.length )
   div.innerHTML = dataList[x]
}
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
<div id='asd'></div>
```

Comment: thank you very much; Do you think it is possible to avoid making a list of sentences as the way you did in the brackets? That's what i tried with the HTML datalist tag, but i didn't manage to link the datalist tag to my javascript function yet. Anyway, i will use your code to try this function thanks again

Comment: how would you like to get the sentences?

Answer (score 0):

This is easy using the function `parseInt()` and `Math.random()*n`:

```js
var yourDataList = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]; // Define datalist
var myBtn = document.getElementById("yourIdHere"); //Declare button, replace yourIdHere with your ID
var randomNum = 0; //Decclre random number
function getRandom() { //Declare your function
  randomNum = parseInt(Math.random() * yourDataList.length); //Get random number between 0 and the length of your datalist
  return yourDataList[randomNum]; //Return your value
}
myBtn.addEventListener("click", function() { //Bind a listener to the button
  alert(getRandom()); //Do whatever you want to with the random value
});
```

```html
<button id = "yourIdHere">Click me!!</button>
```

## **EDIT:**

Using the DOM HTML element `<datalist>` as your input, this is some working code:

```js
var yourDataList = document.getElementById("datalist"); // Define datalist
var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");
var dataListOptionsElems = yourDataList.querySelectorAll("option");//Get all options elements
var dataListOptions = [];//Declare options
for(var i = 0;i<dataListOptionsElems.length;i++){
dataListOptions.push(dataListOptionsElems[i].value);
}
var myBtn = document.getElementById("yourIdHere"); //Declare button, replace yourIdHere with your ID
var randomNum = 0; //Declare random number
function getRandom() { //Declare your function
  randomNum = parseInt(Math.random() * dataListOptions.length); //Get random number between 0 and the length of your datalist
  return dataListOptions[randomNum]; //Return your value
}
myBtn.addEventListener("click", function() { //Bind a listener to the button
  alert(getRandom());
  console.log(getRandom());
  myInput.value = getRandom();
  //Do whatever you want to with the random value
});
```

```html
<button id = "yourIdHere">Click me!!</button>
  <input list="datalist" id="myInput">
  <datalist id="datalist">
    <option value="Option1">
    <option value="Option2">
    <option value="Option3">
    <option value="Option4">
    <option value="Option5">
  </datalist>
<p>Note: the alert box, console message, and input value will not be the same, due to it being random each time the function is called.</p>
```

**[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/82qxwok5/)**

Comment: thank you very much; Do you think it is possible to avoid making a list of "options" as the way you did into brackets? That's what i tried with the HTML datalist tag, but i didn't manage to link the datalist tag to my javascript function yet. I will use your code to try this function thanks again

Comment: So just to clarify, you are using an HTML DOM element `datalist`?

Comment: In case this has to do with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73576402/18591002), I posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73576402/is-it-possible-to-get-a-random-sentence-from-a-google-sheet-and-showing-it-on-my/74649396#74649396).